# Android startActivityForResult and Don't keep activities in developer options

Tags: java, android

Many users report a problem in the google play feedback for an app which seems to happen because of "Don't keep activities" option in developer options. I use startActivityForResult which seems to be useless in this case.

Does anyone have a solution to this? (Except "Use Shared Preferences")
And does anyone know where this problem comes from? I mean it's really weird that many users activated this option - I don't think all of them are developers. Is there any super duper CleanMaster App or sth. like that which turns on that option automatically?

Comment: You might be able to check if that option is turned on and tell your users with a dialog to turn it off.